# Indexed collection of sets and intervals

Tags: elementary-set-theory

After a long break, I've picked up [a book about proofs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321390539) again.

Working through set theory I came across the following question and was wondering if I'm on the right track here. If so, maybe others can use it as some sort of reference to questions regarding this topic.

For a real number $r$:

> $A_r = \{r^2\}$,
>
> $B_r$ is the closed interval $[r - 1, r + 1]$,
>
> $C_r$ is the open interval $(r, \infty)$ and $S = \{1,2,4\}$.

Determine:

> a) $\cup_{ \alpha \in S} A_\alpha$

$\{ 1^2 \} \cup \{ 2^2 \} \cup \{ 4^2 \} = \{ 1, 4, 16 \}$

> b) $\cap_{ \alpha \in S} A_\alpha$

$\{ 1^2 \} \cap \{ 2^2 \} \cap \{ 4^2 \} = \emptyset$

> c) $\cup_{ \alpha \in S} B_\alpha$

$[1 - 1, 1 + 1] \cup [2 - 1, 2 + 1] \cup [4 - 1, 4 + 1]$ =
$[0, 5]$

> d) $\cap_{ \alpha \in S} B_\alpha$

$[1 - 1, 1 + 1] \cap [2 - 1, 2 + 1] \cap [4 - 1, 4 + 1] = \emptyset$

> e) $\cup_{ \alpha \in S} C_\alpha$

$(1, \infty) \cup (2, \infty) \cup (4, \infty) = (1, \infty)$

> f) $\cap_{ \alpha \in S} C_\alpha$

$(1, \infty) \cap (2, \infty) \cap (4, \infty) = (4, \infty)$

Comment: Seems right to me